# DL; Generic reasoning algorithms

Tags: owl, ontology, reasoning, description-logic

Actually, I'm getting lost about what can be done and cannot be done using a reasoner in general.

My question is two fold:

1. I used to think that a reasoner is only dedicated for sumbsumption and taxonomies. Recently, I discovered that a reasoner can be used in multiple ways within some algorithms for example this [reference](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=71208590F14E6430A6BCC7E4FB5CECBA?doi=10.1.1.46.7851&rep=rep1&type=pdf) introduces using a reasoner to search for entities compliant to a specific pattern in the ontology:

   - What is meant by a DL generic reasoning algorithm and how can it
     be implemented through a reasoner?
   - Can you please refer my to
     any references where I can get more familiar to things that can be
     achieved by reasoning algorithms if any?
2. My original problem is that: given an **OWL** ontology and two classes `C1` and `C2`, I want to check whether there is a **functional property chain** connecting them, i.e. 
   let's consider `(C1 P1 C3)`, `(C3 P2 C4)`and `(C4 P3 C2)` where `P1`, `P2` and `P3` are functional object properties, thus the result will be `(P1, P2, P3)` which is the functional property chain connecting `C1` and `C2`.

Comment: "a reasoner can be used in multiple ways" Such as what?  (I see that you've provided a link, but please summarize here.)  Many reasoning tasks can be expressed subsumption.  E.g., asking whether p(a,b) is the same as asking whether "{a} ⊑ ∃p.{b}".

Comment: I quote here about this specific algorithm "This algorithm was conceived to match concepts against patterns to support the pruning of large concept descriptions discarding unimportant aspects. More precisely, given a concept pattern D (i.e., a concept description containing variables) and a concept description C without variables,
the matching problem asks for a substitution σ (of the variables
by concept descriptions) such that C is subsumed by σ(D).

Comment: For instance, considering the pattern “the research interest of those people being only interested in a single research area” (expressed in DL as ∀research-interests.X), and the concept description “those people only having cats as pets and being only interested in AI research” (∀pets.Cat ∩ ∀research-interests.AI), the matching algorithm finds the scientific interests (in this case Artificial Intelligence) described in the concept (i.e., assigns to X the value AI)."